# Microsoft Graph API - Change notification subscription to granular resources

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Is it possible to subscribe to webhook change notification for granular resources or event ?
e.g. to subscribe to resource type "Message" but only when it has attachments ?
Is it possible to use with "fiter" or "search" parameters in the subscription API (web hook). 
any details and examples would be appreciated.

Filters and search doesn't seem to have impact in the subscription api.

Answer (score 0):

The following are valid values for the resource property of the subscription:

- Mail
- Contacts
- Calendars
- Users
- Groups
- Conversations
- Drives
- Security alert

You can only subscribe for the following event:

- Update
- Created
- Deleted

Security alerts are allowed to have filters, but events and other resources not at this moment :(

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#resources-examples)